# How to convert dict to json with specific separation

Tags: python, json, function

I have a line like this and I need to convert it to json format

```
{from:[3,4],to:[7,4],color:2},{from:[3,6],to:[10,6],color:3},{from:[5,8],to:[9,8],color:5},{from:[5,11],to:[10,11],color:6},{from:[1,0],to:[1,11],color:0},{from:[10,1],to:[10,6],color:4},{from:[3,0],to:[8,0],color: 1}
```

Applying this code,  I will transform it, but not completely, as I need

```
def select(value):
    ll = value.split(',{')
    ll = [element.replace("{", '') for element in ll]
    ll = [element.replace("}", '') for element in ll]
    js = {str(i):letter for i,letter in enumerate(ll)}
    js = json.dumps(js)
    return js

total["data_words_selection"] = total["data_words_selection"].map(lambda x: str(x).lstrip("['").rstrip("']")).astype(str)
total['data_words_selection'] = total['data_words_selection'].apply(select)
```

I receive it like this:

```
{
    "0": "from:[3,4],to:[7,4],color:2",
    "1": "from:[3,6],to:[10,6],color:3",
    "2": "from:[5,8],to:[9,8],color:5",
    "3": "from:[5,11],to:[10,11],color:6",
    "4": "from:[1,0],to:[1,11],color:0",
    "5": "from:[10,1],to:[10,6],color:4",
    "6": "from:[3,0],to:[8,0],color:1"
}
```

I get valid json. Please tell me how can I convert this string to this format:

```
{
"0":
    "from":
        "0": "3"
        "1": "4"
"to":
        "0": "7"
        "1": "4"
"color": "2"

"1":
    "from":
        "0": "3"
        "1": "6"
"to":
        "0": "10"
        "1": "5"
"color": "3"
}
```

The result, which I would like to see, was written by hand, sorry for the mistakes. please tell me
This is an example of what it should look like. I hope you understand what I want

Comment: I get different output from your code and it's very unclear how you get the target output. Please give [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The data is stored in a dataframe, so I shortened it a bit and left the essence, now I have added it completely

Comment: What you define as expected output is not JSON. The input is not JSON either. Why is this question tagged [tag:json] if it has nothing to do with that?

Comment: Maybe I don’t understand a little, but if I check the result that it displays for me on the json validity check site, then it shows that the json is valid. That's why I called the result json

Comment: And the final result that I would like to get was drawn to me on paper and I transferred it to you, it is most likely not valid, but I need to get something like this

Comment: The output you show is very much like YAML (well, it's even valid YAML), but with unusual quoted keys. Are that quotes necessary? If not, you could just use `yaml.safe_dump` (PyYAML package) to get this mapping representation.

Comment: If I check it on https://jsonlint.com/, that's not JSON

Comment: if i insert {
    "0": "from:[3,4],to:[7,4],color:2",
    "1": "from:[3,6],to:[10,6],color:3",
    "2": "from:[5,8],to:[9,8],color:5",
    "3": "from:[5,11],to:[10,11],color:6",
    "4": "from:[1,0],to:[1,11],color:0",
    "5": "from:[10,1],to:[10,6],color:4",
    "6": "from:[3,0],to:[8,0],color:1"
} then this is json

Comment: My version of what I wanted to get is not json, but I indicated that they outlined it for me approximately

Answer (score 1):

As other guys said. It is not perfectly clear what you want to do. But maybe this code can help you:

```
import json
import re

input_ = "{from:[3,4],to:[7,4],color:2},{from:[3,6],to:[10,6],color:3},{from:[5,8],to:[9,8],color:5},{from:[5,11],to:[10,11],color:6},{from:[1,0],to:[1,11],color:0},{from:[10,1],to:[10,6],color:4},{from:[3,0],to:[8,0],color:1}"

def parse_json(input_):
    arr = input_.split("},")
    arr = [x+"}" for x in arr]
    arr[-1] = arr[-1][:-1]
    return json.dumps({str(i):add_quotation_marks(x) for i, x in enumerate(arr)})

def add_quotation_marks(input_):
    words = re.findall(r'(\w+:)', input_)
    for word in words:
        input_ = input_.replace(word[:-1], f'"{word[:-1]}"')
    return json.loads(input_)

print(parse_json(input_))
```

List stay as list, but it could be transformed into dict.